# Didnt get design view of web page

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm developing a web application in visual studio 2008.
I didnt get the design view of any web page.
Help me to proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to work with the raw markup, design view is a crutch you should not rely on. However you can right click on the aspx page in question and click 'Convert to Web Application' which should recreate the designer.cs file (see [How do you force Visual Studio 2008 to generate designer.cs e.g. Whatever.aspx.designer.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482473/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-2008-to-generate-designer-cs-e-g-whatever-aspx-d))

Comment: my aspx files design button and split button freezes..
i can able to see only source view

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone...
i solved this issue by uninstalling ms office 2007 from my system.. there is some compatibility issue between ms office 2007 and vs 2008 web components...